# Access parameters of a function with no parameter

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I have a function as:

```
readData = (map read) . words
```

I need to match certain constraints and accordingly return data. Is there any way I can do this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "match certain constraints"? Would it help to rewrite this in "pointful" style? `readData str = map read (words str)`

Comment: @chepner I need the input to be 2 - 10000. Your earlier comment works. Thanks. Can you help me on this?

Comment: You should prove much more information. There's no way we can answer this without wild guessing about what you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume, as seems likely, this function takes a string, splits it into words, and then parses them into integers and you need those integers to be restricted to between 2 and 10,000.

So you can just wrap a check around the list you're already producing. However, to do that you're going to need to change to explicit parameters so that you can talk about them.

```
readData input = map read (words input)
```

Now we can filter it

```
readData input = filter (\n -> n >= 2 && n <= 10000) $ map read (words input)
```

So any out of range numbers just get dropped from the list.

It's best to remember that while point-free style (not using explicit parameters) can be really nice, it's often not possible to express more complex logic with it. I tend to start out by writing my functions with parameters and then taking them out if I realise I can, and if the resulting code looks easier to understand.